# Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99 - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, logging

I'm trying to use the famous DLog macro in my app. I have the below code in my *appname-prefix.pch*, and yes, it is included in my build settings as a **Precompile Prefix Header**

Here's the code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define DLog(...)
#define NSLog(...)
#endif

#define ALog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);

#ifdef DEBUG
#define ULog(fmt, ...)  { UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s\n [Line %d] ", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__]  delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil]; [alert show]; }
#else
#define ULog(...)
#endif
```

Yet I get the error *Implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99* everywhere, including my app delegate. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My _Debug_ variable in my _Custom Compiler Flags, Other C-Flags_ section isn't set. When trying to set it to =1, I get an error _No such file or directory: '=1'_ . Thought I'd add this information.

Comment: Do you have a definition of `NSLog` that references `DLog`?

Comment: You could consider capturing the preprocessor output and examining it.  Presumably you will find places where `DLog` has not been expanded as a macro.  Where those appear might give you a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: If you refer to `DLog` in headers other than the one where it is defined, you should include the one defining it into those headers, rather than relying on the order in which headers are included into a different file to ensure that `DLog` will always be expanded as a macro.  This is a particular case of a good general rule, in fact.

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger for your comments. I do not have a definition of NSLog that references DLog. I'll examine the preprocessor output, though I haven't done such a thing on XCode. Also, DLog is defined once, so the reference to any DLog header would be the same reference. I would think it is being expanded into a macro.

Comment: I think you have missed my third point.  I was not referring to additional *definitions* of `DLog`, but about circumstances under which it is *used* in other headers.